# android map marker using json array values in android

Tags: android, json, google-maps, latitude-longitude, geo

I need to plot map marker using the values which I get from the JSONArray. I have used the following code.It is working fine when I pass the latitude and longitude values directly but when I pass the values fetched from JSONArray the map isnt getting plotted.

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (object.getInt("status") == 200) {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("data");
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject pobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    lat = Double.parseDouble(pobj.getString("latitude"));
                                    lon = Double.parseDouble(pobj.getString("longitude"));                                    pobj.getDouble("latitude")+","+pobj.getDouble("longitude");
                                    Log.i("MAP",""+response);
                                    Log.i("lat-",""+lat);
                                    Log.i("lon-",""+lon);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                                 
    private void DisplayTrack() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:" + lat  + "," + lon + "?q=" + lat  + "," + lon + ")")); //NOT WORKING
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:" + 15.824730932928347  + "," + 74.50431285009074 + "?q=" + 15.824730932928347  + "," + 74.50431285009074 + ")")); //WORKING
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Below is my data:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": "43",
        "site_no": "361",
        "p_id_no": "68-1-361",
        "sas_application_no": "95534",
        "latitude": "15.824730932928347",
        "longitude": "74.50431285009074",
```

Comment: I tried your code & it works for me even with `"geo:" + lat  + ","....`. Can you please confirm there is no json parsing error at your end. Because everything else looks fine.

Comment: @MayurGajra: there is no error but the response is not stored properly "latitude":"1","longitude":"2". This is the response. And the values getting passed are lat and lon both null

Comment: Ok Then. Can you please post a complete parsing you're doing? How are your storing etc.

Comment: @MayurGajra: I have update the code....

Comment: With this logic you're assigning the `lat` & `lon` of the last object in your `jsonArray`.  It's most likely that by the time you reach your last object, one of your object has caused some `JSONException` or  your last element has empty or null value. In any case it's being assigned `null` value. Do check your JSON response fully.

Comment: @MayurGajra: Yes u wer right!! Thank u. Should I also change the method call? Should I call it soon after getting the respone?

Comment: I would request that you update your question with your current state & what's your desired output? what do you want to achieve? Do you want to open the activity with the last object lat/lon you've as soon as the response arrives or anything you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: With this logic you're assigning the `lat`& `lon` of the last object in your `jsonArray`. It's most likely that by the time you reach your last object, one of your object has caused some `JSONException` or your last element has empty or null value. In any case it's being assigned null value. Do check your JSON response fully.

So I created a little demo how you can do it. Read the inline comments to understand:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //declare the global variable, initially they are null
    private Double lat, lon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // prepare request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                            //check
                            if (object.getInt("status") == 200) {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("data");
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    //keep getting the new objects
                                    JSONObject pobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    //assign the last object lat/lon
                                    lat = Double.parseDouble(pobj.getString("latitude"));
                                    lon = Double.parseDouble(pobj.getString("longitude"));
                                }
                                //if they are not null then call the activity
                                if (lat != null && lon != null) {
                                    DisplayTrack(lat, lon);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        // call your request like you do
    }

    //declared the function out of the Network call scope
    private void DisplayTrack(Double lat, Double lon) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:" + lat + "," + lon + "?q=" + lat + "," + lon + ")")); //NOT WORKING
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

Comment: Yes I understood..Thank u